# Getting error on Route attribute in Api method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have created Api controller and trying to add 1 api method but getting error when adding Route attribute on my api method:

This is my method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
 public class MyController : ApiController
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/abc/Get")] //Getting error :type or namespace Route could not be found
        public async Task<object> Get()
        {
        }
    }
```

My dll references:
[image]

But on **Route** Attribute i am getting error:

**Error**:Type or namespace Route could not be found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need to check if you have System.Web.Http assembly in your project references. if you used nuget please check if you have web api packages installed 
you can check it here:

[image: nuget package manager]

Comment: what nuget packages you have installed?

Comment: I added picture to explain what I mean

Comment: Ok i solved this error as per ur suggestion like installing web api thorugh nuget and that solved my error.Thanks